# c# mvc escape json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I use MVC controller to return json:

```
 public JsonResult Json()
        {
            return Json(MyJsonString);
        }
```

I want to Json to be escaped. Does anyone know exact method to accomplish this?
Thanks

EDIT1: json is being sent for flash video player

--MB

Comment: It depends on what you want to do this for. Do you mean you want it to be escaped, so that you can see it on a page in plaintext (for debugging or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a stab at this based on your sample and comments, but is `MyJsonString` a string that is already JSON encoded? It sounds like it is, and therefor it is being double encoded.

If so, then you may have better luck returning the object that you used to create the JSON encoded string, like:

```
public virtual ActionResult Json()
    {
        var someObject = MethodThatCreatesAnObject();
        //or just create it on the fly
        //var someObject = new { val1 = "value", val2 = "another" };
        return Json(someObject);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could create a control that has string as its model type and that doesn't have any content in it except `<%: Model %>` and then you could do something like:

```
public virtual ActionResult Json()
    {
        return ActionResult("MyJsonControl", MyJsonString);
    }
```

But I'd really look into the former before going with the latter.